Is there a way to affect differents ways to be parsed for the same expression ? (bison)
So, I'm currently working on the grammar of a language for a project and here is the thing. I want it to act differently wether or not there is a semi-colon at the end. For instance the expressions "1+2" and "1+2;" should be treated differently. This is easy to do, but what happens if we have this expression "1+2 * 3;" then we will have two expressions inside one: (1+(expr); where expr is 2 * 3).
And here is the problem, in such a case  2 * 3 will be treated as a "non-semi-colon" expression even if it is inside an expression with a semicolon at the end. I'd like to change that in order that the child expression inherit the semicolon from the root expression.
So the OpAdd, OpMult, OpDivF, OpSub functions are describing the way non-semicolon expressions should be treated, and OpAdd2, OpMult2, OpDivF2, OpSu2b functions are describing the way semicolon expressions should be treated. So here are the rules of the grammar (its .yy by the way):
`%%
program
    : stmt
    ;

stmt
    : assignment
    | expression
    | expression_with_semicolon
    | str 
    ;

assignment
    : KW_LET id OP_ASSIGN expression {
        $$ = Node::add<ast::OpAssignLiteral>($2, $4);
    }
    | KW_LET id OP_COLON type OP_ASSIGN expression {
        $$ = Node::add<ast::OpAssignTypeAndLiteral>($2, $4, $6);
    }
    | KW_LET id OP_COLON type {
        $$ = Node::add<ast::OpAssignType>($2, $4);
    }
    ;

id
    : IDENTIFIER { $$ = Node::add<ast::Identifier>(curtoken); }
    ;

expression
    : expression OP_PLUS expression { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpAdd>($1, $3); }
    | expression OP_MINUS expression { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpSub>($1, $3); }
    | term
    ;

expression_with_semicolon
    : expression OP_PLUS expression OP_SEMICOLON { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpAdd2>($1, $3); }
    | expression OP_MINUS expression OP_SEMICOLON { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpSub2>($1, $3); }
    | term_with_semicolon
    ;

term
    : term OP_MULT term { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpMult>($1, $3); }
    | term OP_DIVF term { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpDivF>($1, $3); }
    | factor
    ;

term_with_semicolon
    : term OP_MULT term OP_SEMICOLON { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpMult2>($1, $3); }
    | term OP_DIVF term OP_SEMICOLON { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpDivF2>($1, $3); }
    | factor OP_SEMICOLON { $$ = $1; }
    ;
    
factor
    : posneg
    | OP_LPAREN expression OP_RPAREN { $$ = $2; }
    ;

posneg
    : L_INTEGER { $$ = Node::add<ast::Integer>(curtoken); }
    | OP_PLUS factor { $$ = Node::add<ast::SignedNode>(OP_PLUS, $2); }
    | OP_MINUS factor { $$ = Node::add<ast::SignedNode>(OP_MINUS, $2); }
    ;

type
    : TYPE { $$ = Node::add<ast::Type>(curtoken); }
    ;

str
    : SSTRING OP_SEMICOLON { $$ = Node::add<ast::String>(curtoken); }
    ;
%%`

This code is always working with "non-semicolons expressions" and working for semi-colon expressions as long as there are not encapsulated into other. I have tried adding a boolean flag in order to put it to "true" when we are in a semi-colon expression but it didn't work, I believe it is because you can't change a global variable into a parser rule. I also tried writing other rules in order to manage non-semicolon expressions inside a semi-colon expression but it was doing a conflict with the expression rule:
`expression_with_semicolon_inner
    : expression OP_PLUS term { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpAdd2>($1, $3); }
    | expression OP_MINUS term { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpSub2>($1, $3); }
    | term_with_semicolon_inner
    ;

term_with_semicolon_inner
    : term OP_MULT factor { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpMult2>($1, $3); }
    | term OP_DIVF factor { $$ = Node::add<ast::OpDivF2>($1, $3); }
    | posneg { $$ = $1; }
    ;`

I am running out of solutions so if anyone has suggestions I would be glad to try it.

IMO, expression_with_semicolon should not be build with expression.

certainly but what should I put instead then

Similarly to expression_with_semicolon_inner but replacing expression by expression_with_semicolon_inner

I tried it but, it does a conflict with expression because expression_with_semicolon_inner  and expression are basically becoming the same rule

Else there is still expression_with_semicolon: expression OP_SEMICOLON {  $$ =   Transform_to_semicolon($1);}

The simplest and most flexible way to do what you (probably) want is to not deal with the semicolons at the expression/term/factor level and just at the stmt level.  So get rid of all the _with_semicolon rules and instead just have:
stmt : assignment   { .. do something }
     | expression   { $$ = $1; }
     | expression OP_SEMICOLON { $$ = modify_for_semicolon($1); }
     ;

So now you have a function modify_for_semicolon that takes a parsed expression (the AST you've created in the expression/term/factor rules), and modifies it to reflect the fact that it is followed by a semicolon.
